# How can I use the same code without having to retype it every time in different subs?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, simplify

So I have a textbox that I only want to allow numbers in, I have the code to do it and it works fine. However I want to use it in a few textboxes, how can I use the same code without having to retype it in each textbox's KeyDown and KeyPress Subs?

The code I'm using in the KeyDown Subs is

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Back Then
        BACKSPACE = True
    Else
        BACKSPACE = False
    End If
```

and in the KeyPress subs I'm using

```
If BACKSPACE = False Then
        Dim allowedChars As String = "0123456789"
        If allowedChars.IndexOf(e.KeyChar) = -1 Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If
```

I'm using this code for a few textboxes and was wondering how I can clean this up a bit. Can I? Thank you for your help and time!

Comment: Is this WPF / Win Forms / ASP.NET?

Comment: This is in Win Forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make your own version of the TextBox control that inherits from the base TextBox and extends it with your custom code.

For example:

```
Public Class CleverTextBox
    Inherits TextBox

    Private BACKSPACE As Boolean = False

    Private Sub CleverTextBox_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Back Then
            BACKSPACE = True
        Else
            BACKSPACE = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CleverTextBox_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
        If BACKSPACE = False Then
            Dim allowedChars As String = "0123456789"
            If allowedChars.IndexOf(e.KeyChar) = -1 Then
                e.Handled = True
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then recompile your project, and you should see that the new `CleverTextBox` control has been added to the Toolbox panel, and you can drag and drop it on to your form.

Comment: Excellent, glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

you could  simply set the handler for the event to handle the other objects and they will share that code

```
    Private Sub txtDim0_Validated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtDim0.Validated, txtDim1.Validated, txtDim2.Validated, txtDim3.Validated, txtDim4.Validated, txtDim5.Validated, txtDim7.Validated, txtDim7.Validated

    Dim iNewIndex As Integer

    If ErrorProvider1.Tag <> "" Then
        For icount = 0 To Len(ErrorProvider1.Tag) - 1
            iNewIndex = Val(ErrorProvider1.Tag.ToString.Substring(icount, 1))
            ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtDims(iNewIndex), String.Empty)
        Next
        ErrorProvider1.Tag = ""
    Else
        ' get the index based on the name
        Dim index As Integer = Val(sender.name.ToString.Substring(Len("txtDim")))
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtDims(index), String.Empty)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I would try this also, however I don't completely understand how this works.